# Find several intersections between line and curve using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, draw, intersections, tikz-graphdrawing

I want to find the intersections between the orange dashed line and the blue curve using the package tikz, see the screenshot below. As can be seen, only the first intersection is shown. However, I want to mark all intersections between the line and the curve using red markers, not only the first one. I am thinking about using `\foreach{}` but I am quite new to this package and I am not sure how this should be implemented.

[image: screenshot]

I have added the following lines in my preamble:

```
\usepackage{tikz}    
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
```

The plot shown in the screenshot is achieved through the following lines:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:10]
\draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (10.2,0) node[right] {$t$}; 
\draw[->] (0,-1.4) -- (0,1.4) node[above] {$x(t)$};
\draw[color=orange, dashed, name path=plotA] plot (\x,0.75) node[right] {$x = a$}; 
\draw[color=blue, name path=plotB] plot[samples=1000] (\x,{sin(\x * 320)}) node[right] {$x(t) = \sin(t)$};
\path [name intersections={of=plotA and plotB,by=E}];
\node [fill=red,inner sep=1pt] at (E) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find some examples in `TikZ` documentation: [pages 145-146](https://texdoc.org/serve/pgf/0#page=145)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:10]
\draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (10.2,0) node[right] {$t$}; 
\draw[->] (0,-1.4) -- (0,1.4) node[above] {$x(t)$};
\draw[color=orange, dashed, name path=plotA] plot (\x,0.75) node[right] {$x = a$}; 
\draw[color=blue, name path=plotB] plot[samples=1000] (\x,{sin(\x * 320)}) node[right] {$x(t) = \sin(t)$};
\fill [name intersections={of=plotA and plotB, name=E, total=\t}]
[red] 
\foreach \s in {1,2,...,\t}{(E-\s) circle (2pt)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm.